# twocolumnにおけるfootnoteのスタイルについて

Tags: latex

twocolumnモードで文書をつくるとき、footnoteはそれぞれのカラムに用意され、ひとつのページにつき左右で2つのfootnote領域が表示されます。これをひとつにまとめるというのか、onecolumnと同じように、ページにつき1つのfootnote領域として表示する方法はありますか？
現在使っているのはplatex,article.clsですが、これにこだわるわけではありません。前述のようなスタイルを実現するドキュメントクラス・パッケージ等の情報をお教えいただけるだけでも、大変助かります。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

参考として:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent hello\footnote{english}\newpage%
\noindent guten tag\footnote{deutsch}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multicol`という標準的なパッケージを使えば、通常の`\footnote`コマンドで横幅いっぱいに脚注が出力されます。ただし、文書全体を`multicols`という環境に入れる必要があります。トップレベルに書かれた文書全体について脚注を1列で出力するようなクラスやスタイルを書くことは、通常のTeXではかなり困難な作業になりそうです（もしかしたら不可能かも）。

Answer (score 0):

keiichiro shikanoさんの解答を参考に、試してみました。動作させる際につまづいた点をまとめておきます。サンプルでは以下のような問題はあります:

- `multicols`環境の中では`figure,table`環境には`[H]`オプションをつけないといけない（hereパッケージが必要）
- `multicols`の中で`\footnotemark`を使うと番号がずれてしまう
- `\footnoterule`を手動で設定する必要がある

これらはこの質問とは関係がないと思われるので、特に言及はしません。

サンプルコード:

```
\documentclass[a4paper%,twocolumn
]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{here}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@\hrule\@width\textwidth\kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}%
  \begin{table}[H]%
    \centering%
    \caption{Lorem ipsum}%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}%
      \hline%
      dolor & sit & amet \\%
      \hline%
      consectetuer\footnotemark & adipiscing & elit \\%
      \hline%
      ut & purus & elit\footnotemark\\%
      \hline%
    \end{tabular}%
  \end{table}%
  \footnotetext{helllo world}%
  \footnotetext{test test}%
  \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}%
  \begin{figure}[H]%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{Lorem ipsum}%
  \end{figure}%
  \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}%
\end{multicols}%
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]